# How to mention different modules

Tags: haskell

I do not know how to import two different modules at the same time. THe following code

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map 
import Data.List

phoneBookToList :: (Ord k) => [(k,String)] -> Map.Map k String
phoneBookToList xs = Map.fromListWith (\n1 n2 -> n1 ++ ", " ++ n2) xs

phoneBookFromWithList :: (Ord k) => [(k,a)] -> Map k [a]
phoneBookFromWithList = Map.fromListWith (++)  $ map (\(k,a) -> (k,[a]))
```

throws this error

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class `Map'
Perhaps you meant `Map.Map' (imported from Data.Map)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The `map (\(k,a) -> (k,[a]))` I am trying to use it from the default Prelude module. I tried `Data.List.map (\(k,a) -> (k,[a]))`, but still get an error. It wordks as a GHCi command though. Thanks in advance

Comment: `map` and `Data.List.map` are identical.

Comment: Yes, I read that, can you please tell why I am getting the error?

Comment: The compiler is complaining about the type signature `(Ord k) => [(k,a)] -> Map k [a]` - the type `Map` is only imported qualified, hence you must write `Map.Map` (as you did in the other type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `Data.Map` qualified as `Map`, but trying to refer to the `Map` data type without qualification.

You need to change `Map k [a]` in the type signature of `phoneBookFromWithList` to `Map.Map k [a]` in order to properly refer to the `Map` data type.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got confused with the error message.